# Doctrine ORM mapping not working on separated Symfony 2 bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony bundle that uses doctrine orm with an entity class like this

```
namespace Acme\ECWDatabaseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Bundle
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="forecast.Bundle")
 */
class Bundle
{
```

I've separated it out into it's own bundle so that all our apps can pull this in via composer. Running on my dev machine this works ok, running on the test server it works fine when built into an app (in the `src` folder). But by itself I get lots and lots of errors like this

`Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity" in class Acme\ECWDatabaseBundle\Entity\Bundle does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.`

This is a section of the composer file in the separated bundle

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.17",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/symfony" : "2.*@stable",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "~2.7.0"
}
```

An extract from the Resources/config/Doctrine/bundle.orm.yml file

```
Acme\ECWDatabaseBundle\Entity\Bundle:
type: entity
table: forecast.Bundle
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: SEQUENCE
fields:
    ecoconnect_id:
        type: integer
        nullable: true
    configuration_name:
        type: string
        length: 500
        nullable: true
    latitude:
        type: float
        nullable: true
    longitude:
        type: float
        nullable: true
```

Update: stack trace reported from the failing test

```
Niwa\ECWDatabaseBundle\Tests\Entity\BundleEntityTest::testRecentBundlePeriods
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity" in class Niwa\ECWDatabaseBundle\Entity\Bundle does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:54
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php:708
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php:641
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php:334
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationReader.php:194
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/FileCacheReader.php:95
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php:61
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:103
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:113
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:318
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:211
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:268
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:682
/repository/jenkins/jobs/ECWDatabaseBundle/workspace/Tests/Entity/BundleEntityTest.php:36
```

Code snippet from BundleEntityTest.php

```
class BundleEntityTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setUp()
    {       
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
                ->get('doctrine')
                ->getManager()
                ;
    }
    public function testRecentBundlePeriods()
    {

        $bundleRepository = $this->em->getRepository('NiwaECWDatabaseBundle:Bundle');
```

Comment: In your separated bundle, have you told composer that it is a Symfony bundle? You can do this with `"type": "symfony-bundle",`, or see [FOSUserBundle composer.json](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/composer.json#L3) for further details.

Comment: It wasn't there, so I tried it but it made no difference.

Comment: How exactly do you use a Symfony Bundle "by itself"?

Comment: It's not a Symfony app with this bundle pulled into the vendors. It's this bundle being the main source. Then it has its own composer.json which pulls in other bundles it needs.

Answer (score 0):

From Doctrine Documentation ([annotations](http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations.html)):

> How are these annotations loaded? From looking at the code you could
>   guess that the ORM Mapping, ... can just be loaded using the defined
>   PHP autoloaders. **This is not the case however**: For error handling
>   reasons every check for class existence inside the AnnotationReader
>   sets the second parameter $autoload of class_exists($name, $autoload)
>   to false. To work flawlessly the AnnotationReader requires silent
>   autoloaders which many autoloaders are not. Silent autoloading is NOT
>   part of the PSR-0 specification for autoloading.

So you may want to include `"doctrine/annotations"` in composer.json or if this fails have a closer look to the documentation.

Comment: I have PSR-4 autoloading and `doctrine/annotations` is loaded in because doctrine/common requires it.

Answer (score 0):

## Context

> - Running on my dev machine this works ok.
> - Running on the test server it works fine when built into an app (in the src folder).
> - But by itself I get lots and lots of errors like this.

What I gather from this is that you're trying to use the bundle without Symfony itself. I'm not really sure how you would do that (apart from testing), but I can't extrapolate anything else from these statements.

If I'm wrong, than this answer won't make any sense :)

## The problem

For the annotations to function correctly, Doctrine needs to be configured. Configuration of Doctrine in Symfony is typically done by/with the [DoctrineBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle).

The same goes for many other things related to Symfony, Doctrine and other libraries/bundles.

So in order for the annotations to function correctly, you'll need to register the DoctrineBundle and your bundle in Symfony, and maybe change the Symfony configuration files a bit.

## Testing

Testing the bundle in isolation (in some CI environment) would be a case where you want to "use" the bundle by itself. In this case you're running unit-test.

As soon as you want to run other kind of tests, like integration tests, you'll need to configure any dependencies you want to integrate with. Simply installing those dependencies with Composer isn't enough.

You can consult the [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html) on how to configure Doctrine manually in your test suite.

Comment: I am not quite running this bundle without Symfony itself, Symfony is listed in the composer.json as a a require-dev and is being pulled down into the vendor folder. As are the other parts such as doctrine and monolog. This procedure runs fine on my dev machine, for this bundle and the others I am developing. However the same procedure does not work on my automated test server for this one bundle with all the Doctrine annotations, the other bundles work fine, including those that need a AppKernel file and other Symfony bits.

Comment: You should mention _in your question_ that you are trying to test your bundle in isolation in some CI environment, what testing framework you're using, and what kind of tests you're running.

Comment: "... for this one bundle ..., the other bundles work fine" What does this setup look like?

Comment: Each set up is the same. A symfony bundle that you could find in your `vendor` folder is used as the main source. It has its own composer.json and its own vendor folder. The one that requires Doctrine's annotations is failing, the others are not.

Comment: The CI system (Jenkins) is irrelevant in this case, because the same thing occurs when run from the command line, there is something missing on my test server that my dev machine has that enables it to understand the annotations and I can't tell what it is.

Comment: If the bundle that's failing is the only one that uses Doctrine ORM annotations, I would say those annotations aren't registered properly. That's why I'm asking for the setup. What have you done to configure Doctrine in that setup?

Comment: The only setup I have is show in the original question. Composer.json requires `doctrine-bundle` which ini turn requires `doctrine-annotations`. It is there in my vendor folder, as is doctrine ORM. Then the entity class says it uses Doctrine/ORM/Mapping. Is there another part of the set up I should show?

Comment: I really appreciate your patience, can you explain what part of the configuration you mean. I've added part of he bundle.orm.yml file in case that is what you mean. I can't think of another file that would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack-trace of the errors you get? That would give some indication of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanx, now can you also post the content of `BundleEntityTest.php`, at least the method which contains line 36, together with any other methods it calls, and a setup method if it's used? (phpunit has `setUp()` for that).

Comment: Done. The last line I quoted is line 36 where it all falls down.

Comment: Thanx! I'm of to bed now, I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback! I'm kind of at a loss here. This test setup (using `KernelTestCase`) is meant for testing the entire application, not just a single bundle. A bundle doesn't have a kernel, or configuration. So I'm not sure what you did to get it running, but you have to have something custom in place. My only advise boils down to what I've already said: Try to fix the configuration of Doctrine...

Comment: Yup, that's why I'm here.

Comment: @Craig You probably don't know about this issue anymore, but if you do so: Make sure that your autoloader ist registered at AnnotationRegistry. Within symfony, this is typically done in app/autoload.php, but you may have included vendor/autoload.php in your phpUnit setup.